# Accessing OAuthOptions From OAuthMiddleware .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I am trying to access the [OAuthOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.oauthoptions?view=aspnetcore-1.1) provided to the [AuthenticationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.googleextensions.addgoogle?view=aspnetcore-3.0#Microsoft_Extensions_DependencyInjection_GoogleExtensions_AddGoogle_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_AuthenticationBuilder_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_Google_GoogleOptions__) during ConfigureServices. I am specifically hoping to get access to UserInformationEndpoint.

**Goal**: I am trying to build an custom grant for IdentityServer4 and I don't want to have to hardcode the UserInformationEndpoint for external providers.

An example of authentication setup

```
services.AddAuthentication ()
        .AddGoogle (options => {
           options.ClientId = "";
           options.ClientSecret = "";
        });
```

Later in my code

```
public class ExternalGrantValidator: IExtensionGrantValidator {
        private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider _schemeProvider;

        public ExternalGrantValidator (IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemeProvider) {
            _schemeProvider = schemeProvider;
        }

        public async Task ValidateAsync (ExtensionGrantValidationContext context) {
            var provider = context.Request.Raw.Get ("provider");
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (provider)) {
                context.Result = new GrantValidationResult (TokenRequestErrors.InvalidRequest, "provider is required");
                return;
            }
            var schemeProvider = await _schemeProvider.GetSchemeAsync (provider);
            // Do something to get OAuthOptions for scheme that was setup in ConfigureServices
        } 
}
```